# How to filter an array of arrays based on values of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays `playerMoves` and `movesList`. Like this.

```
var playerMoves= [4, 6];
var movesList= [[0,1,2],[0,3,6]];
```

I need to filter the `movesList` array such that values of `playerMoves` array should not be present in each array of `movesList`.

```
console.log(move);
// should return [0,1,2]
```

My attempt

```
var playerMoves= [4, 6];
var movesList= [[0,1,2],[0,3,6]];
var move =  movesList.filter(v => v.filter(c => {
   return playerMoves.indexOf(c) === -1;
}));
console.log(move);
```

Comment: and what happened? Did it work?

Answer (score 3):

You can use mix of `Array#filter`, `Array#every` and `Array#includes`.

```js
let playerMoves = [4, 6];
let movesList = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [5, 7, 9],
];

let res = movesList.filter(v => v.every(c => !playerMoves.includes(c)));

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```